# How to scroll horizontally in radare2

Tags: c++, radare2

I have opened a binary compiled from c++ code and function names are too long for my screen. I cannot read the whole function (also i can't see the comment i add after the line).
This is an example of what it looks like:

```
│   ; CODE XREF from main @ 0x12a5(x)
│       └─> 0x000012aa      488bbd70ffff.  mov rdi, qword [var_90h] 
│           0x000012b1      488d75b8       lea rsi, [*password_str] 
│           0x000012b5      e8e6fdffff     call method std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator>><char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_tr <----over here  
│       ┌─< 0x000012ba      e900000000     jmp 0x12bf
```

How to scroll the screen horizontally, or at least enable line wrap so I can see the whole thing?